# how to generate a checksum for a war file in maven

Tags: java, maven, war

I have inherited a project which uses a maven pom file to build the .war file and we have a request to generate a checksum of the .war file, so my question is, can this be done in the maven pom file? and what plugin if any is needed and how to configure it?

we use the `maven-war-plugin` for building

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>target/minifiedOutput</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

is it possible to use the `maven-install-plugin` to generate a checksum of the output war file, searching around the subject it seems to provide checksum functionality but it isn't clear to me how to integrate it with the existing pom file?

Comment: If you do a mvn deploy checksums will be generated. For what are those checksums needed?

Comment: people in a deployment team want them so they can check that it has been copied from one environment to another correctly. we currently use beanstalk-maven-plugin to copy the built war file over to amazon elastic beanstalk dev environment, when it's passed testing the deployment team take it and put it on a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Maven install plugin :https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/plugin-info.html , set the property in the configuration: createChecksum to true. This is a common practice.

There's also other plugins :
http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/